# How to see a SOAP message in WCF service before any contract work is performed?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have a WCF service that is derived from a WSDL provided by a vendor.  When the vendor's client calls my service they receive an error "`The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.`"

I would like to look at the incoming SOAP message before this error is thrown.

I have tried building an attribute with the `IServiceBehavior`:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
 public sealed class AuditServiceBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
 {
    public AuditServiceBehavior() {  }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("AuditService.AddBindingParameters called.");
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        // Seems like the right place to invoke something?
        Trace.TraceInformation("AuditService.ApplyDispatchBehavior called.");
    }
 }
```

Adding this attribute to my service implementation allows me to see the Trace messages, but these occur when the service is started.  I added an attribute with `IOperationBehavior` but it seems like all the methods here take place after contracts are resolved.

What do I need to do to see the incoming SOAP?

Comment: Have a look at WCF tracing and in particular [Message logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging#message-logging). When you log messages at the transport level, I figure you should be able to read your message (unless you're using a streamed transport)

Answer (score 0):

You could customize an ActionMessageFilter , ActionMessageFilter is used to match action of a soap message.

```
public  class MyActionMesageFilter:ActionMessageFilter
{
    public MyActionMesageFilter(params string[] actions):base(actions)
    {

    }

    public override bool Match(Message message)
    {
        string mes = message.ToString();
        bool re = base.Match(message);
       string action = message.Headers.Action;
        return  re;
    }
}
```

Add an endpointBehavior.

```
 public class ReplaceActionFilterEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {

                   endpointDispatcher.AddressFilter = new MyActionMesageFilter("http://tempuri.org/IEmployeeService/GetEmployee");

    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {

    }
}
```

And the host.

```
 using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service.EmployeeService)))
        {
            host.Description.Endpoints[0].EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ReplaceActionFilterEndpointBehavior());
            host.Opened += delegate
            {
                Console.WriteLine("hello");
            };
            host.Open();
              Console.Read();
        }
```

The result.

[image]

For more information about customizing ActionMessageFilter, you could refer to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-filter